# How to set the rendering mode of IE8 permanently to IE7?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, website, internet-explorer-8

Currently when I want to check how web pages look and behave in IE7, I switch the rendering mode of Internet Explorer 8 to IE7 under "Developer Tools". Unfortunately this procedure needs to be repeated for every new tab and window.

Is there a way to make that selection permanent?

**Edit:** Virtual PC or equivalents is something I'd rather avoid. In this case, the rendering accuracy of the above-mentioned approach is good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comments, Jason's [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/199778/how-to-set-the-rendering-mode-of-ie8-permanently-to-ie7/199868#199868) about using the free VHD's provided by Microsoft to use IE7 itself for testing is really the best way to go - how are we to know that IE8 is entirely accurate when trying to emulate IE7?

---

However, if you really wish to use compatibilty mode, and you are testing a site that you control, you can add the following meta-header. Obviously, you'll probably only want to do this while testing.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

When IE8 loads a page with this in the header it will *automatically* switch in to IE7 compatiblity mode.

You may also find it useful to read the Microsoft MSDN article [Defining Document Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier for you to use the Vista/IE7 [IE Application Compatibility VHD](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en) for VirtualPC.

Comment: I suppose it depends on the definition of "easier": I'd have to download the thing, install it and run Virtual PC every time I want to look at a webpage. Not to mention the 2GB RAM recommendation of VPC.

Comment: @Saul: Well, doing all those things does not take long, and is not difficult to do.  As for RAM, having more is always better.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but I am not looking for a virtual pc solution.

Comment: @Saul, if you want to *accurately* test how a web site looks in IE7, then surely using IE7 for the job is the best way to do it? Even if it requires a little more effort, it's the correct way, and is exactly why MS provides these VHD's with versions of IE - so that web developers can test accurately without having to buy and run several different OSes and machines!

Comment: @DMA57361: So far I am satisfied with the accuracy provided by "Developer Tools" option in IE8. That is reason why I am looking for configuration advice and not something else.